# Playa select not displaying content after upgrade EE1 to EE2

Tags: playa

I've upgraded from EE1 to EE2 and downloaded the latest version of Playa for our project.

Upgrade seemed to go as planned as the admin is all cool and drop panes and selects display the correct data etc.

The drop panes fields display perfectly on the front end templates but for some reason the fields using selects do not display on the front end. The select is showing the correctly selected channel entry in the admin though which is strange.

The database is showing the following data in the field:

[15278] [aquaforce-awards-2012] Aquaforce Awards 2012

Which all seems good but my frontend template tags spit out nothing.

Cheers
Jonny

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're still using the old, pre-2.0 Playa syntax - which was simply `{related_entries}` and `{reverse_related_entries}`?

Since 2.0, Playa has had its [own template tags](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/field.html).

Comment: I'm just using the custom field tag i.e:

{homeGallery}

This is working for all my drop pane playa fields just selects are not showing in my templates.

Comment: Playa has required a tag pair, at least since 4.0, maybe earlier. Try using `{homeGallery}{title}{/homeGallery}`.

Comment: I'm using the tag pair but for some reason the select this playa tag pair is empty whilst others in the same post are working. I just can work it out. The data is correct:

[15067] [asa-national-county-team-championships-2011] ASA National County Team Championships 2011

There are playa fields in the same post that are outputting fine. Post are open and present etc.

Comment: I am using multi-site manager by the way and I've just noticed that this is the only playa field pulling from the "default_site" where the other playa fields are pulling from the same site, which in this case is site 3.

Comment: I still haven't got anywhere with this. Playa outputting zero on the frontend. Anyone have any tips for debugging?

Comment: The playa module seems not to return any results in the _parse_relationships function when it runs the:

return $Channel->entries();

Even though it has an entry_id and $this->EE->TMPL->var_single have been set.

Comment: I need help or my head will explode!!!

Comment: Have you tried adding a `site` parameter, since it's pulling from another site? `{homeGallery site="site_name"}{title}{/homeGallery}`?

Comment: I hadn't no Derek, that would be far to simple.

And guess what it works, I love you. I was delving into the module trying to find a solution as it didn't need a site parameter in EE1.